# Parameterized query fails when inserting certain Unicode characters

Tags: .net, driver, informix

I have a problem when trying to insert certain characters through query with parameters.

When I run the following query (no parameters involved), everything works fine.

```
string insertQuery = "insert into 'testschema'.texttypestestobject(columnshortstring,columnlongstring)values('¬','test')";
DB2Command myCommand = new DB2Command(insertQuery, conn);
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

However, if I run the query like the following, it fails.

```
string insertQuery = "insert into 'testschema'.texttypestestobject(columnshortstring,columnlongstring)values(@p0,@p1')";
DB2Command myCommand = new DB2Command(insertQuery, conn);
myCommand.Parameters.Add(new DB2Parameter("@p0", "¬"));
myCommand.Parameters.Add(new DB2Parameter("@p1", "test"));
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The error is:

```
Executing Sql 'insert into 'testschema'.texttypestestobject(columnshortstring,columnlongstring)values(@p0,@p1)'
with parameters '{¬},{ test}' exception 'IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Exception (0x80004005):
ERROR [IX000] [IBM][IDS/NT64] Code-set conversion function failed due to illegal
sequence or invalid value.
```

Informix server 11.70 (64 bit) and Client SDK 3.50 is installed, and working properly. Database is created with en_US.utf8 or cs_CZ.8859-2.

**One of the characters that fail is '¬' (Unicode 172).**

Has anyone seen this error? What could be the cause? Is there some additional configuration that needs to be performed on the driver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a response from ibm developer forum. This was a bug that was fixed with the latest fix pack.

It can be resolved by either installing the fix pack or setting the environment variable  DB2CODEPAGE=1208

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14779728&#14779728